# Can you combine dhcp dynamic dns updates and static IPs in the same Bind zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, bind, dynamic

I'm in the process of configuring ISC dhcpd and Bind9 on SLES Linux in our office for internal DNS.  I'd like to put everything in one zone, city.domain.tld for example.  I can get the dhcpd server to update the zone, but if I add static records to the zone (a new file server with it's ip for example) Bind complains about the journal no longer matching.

Assigning fixed IPs via dhcp to the servers is not a solution because dhcpd doesn't send updates to the DNS for fix IPs.

I could use two separate zones, one with static IPs and one for the dynamic updates, but I'd rather not have to go all the work stations (80ish) and add the second search suffix.

Workstations are a mix of Windows, Linux and MAC.  No domains or active directory.

Any suggestions?  Is deleting the journal and letting DHCP re-update the dns the only solution? Searching Google didn't turn anything up.

2010.7.14 Update:
Here are the version numbers:

- bind-9.3.2-17.15
- dhcpcd-1.3.22pl4-223.2
- SLES 10 i386

Upgrading to a newer version of Bind/dhcpd is not out of the question if it solves the problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running a recent version of bind later then 9.3.0?

If so you can use the command `rndc freeze zone.tld` to freeze the zone.  Once it is in this state dynamic update requests will be rejected and you can manually edit the zone database.  Use the command `rndc unfreeze zone.tld` to return the zone to a point that will allow dynamic updates.  You do need to update the serial number if you manually make changes.

[Reference](http://www.bind9.net/manual/bind/9.3.1/Bv9ARM.ch04.html#dynamic_update)

Comment: It's `thaw`, not `unfreeze`, but this is right.

Comment: Agreed. Seems the docs and the actual command differ.  Bv9.3 ARM says "unfreeze" but rndc's help command says "thaw".

Answer (score 3):

You can make dhcp update fixed IP assignments on the DNS using these two parameters in the global section of your dhcpd.conf:

```
update-static-leases on;
use-host-decl-names on;
```

And in each host section you should add the `ddns-hostname` option (Only if the host does not provide your name to dhcp at the time of requesting the ip). Example:

```
host database {
     hardware ethernet 00:26:73:66: e9: 9b;
     fixed-address 192.168.0.1;
     ddns-hostname "database";
}
```

You can also see this link for more information:

[dhcpd.conf Manpage](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpd.conf.5.html)